# How to get ROWID in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, tablecolumn, rowid

consider this simple table(tbl1):

```
A|first letter
B|second letter
C|third letter
```

first column is **letter** and second column is **desc**

I can do this query without any problem:

```
select * from tbl1 where letter='B'      -->>second letter
```

My question is: how I can get(retrieve) the **ROWID** of the result row?

Comment: Can you give more detail what you mean?

Comment: use `rowid` keyword.. http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
SELECT rowid, * FROM tbl1 WHERE letter = 'B'
```

Comment: how I do it using the function query of SQLiteDatabase in android?

Comment: how to retrieve that rowid with get column Index ?

Comment: @NoorHossain In exactly the same way as with any other column.

Answer (score 0):

You can get **ROWID** as shown below according to [the doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid):

```sql
SELECT rowid FROM person;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT oid FROM person;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT _rowid_ FROM person;
```

In addition, you cannot show **ROWID** even the commands below:

```
PRAGMA table_info('person');
```

Or:

```
.schema person
```