# PHP SQLITE3 Can't get rowid

Tags: php, sqlite

so I have a column in one of my tables named 'rowid' and after running an SQL Select * followed by a foreach to get each individual value, I get an error when trying to grab the rowid data. Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_settings WHERE Username = ?";
$result= $database->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(1, $User);
$result->execute();


    foreach($result as $row){
        echo $row['Username'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row['Firstname'] ." ". $row['Lastname'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $row['Birthday'] ." ". $row['Location'] ." ". $row['Gender'] ." ". $row['rowid'];
        echo "<br>";
```

everything else works as it should except for the $row['rowid'];

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Seeing that you're using mixed-case letters for the others, have you tried `$row['Rowid']`? When using column names, they stand at being case-sensitive, which most of the time they are.

Comment: Since the other columns are uppercase could it be that rowid is really 'RowId'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sqlite get ROWID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570096/sqlite-get-rowid)

Comment: @barell, had no idea sqlite has this feature

Comment: Great, got it to work. Thanks for the link barell. I must have missed it while searching.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to SELECT rowid,* FROM ...