# Why is rowid not contained in asterisk wildcard queries?

Tags: sqlite

In sqlite the query:

> select * from [....]

is often implemented to grab *all* the info associated with pertinent entries.

But, as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570096/sqlite-get-rowid?noredirect=1&lq=1) asks, rowid is not one of the items returned with *select all*.

Why is rowid not automatically returned with a select all search?

Comment: The fact that you linked to a related question makes this likely a duplicate of that very question, because for the most part "why" question are often off topic.  The answers will either generate opinionated guesses and/or the truth is likely that someone made an arbitrary design decision without some deep reason.  I hope my answer actually answers the question, but for the most part it is irrelevant since sqlite provides a reasonable and well known way to get the rowid in the query.

Answer (score 1):

All RDBMS (relational database management systems) implement some way to distinguish between rows in a table regardless of what keys are defined by the user.  Otherwise there would be no way for the system to distinguish between rows for internal processing.  Other systems also do not reveal their internal record-keeping metadata in `*` queries and only include user-defined columns.  The fact that sqlite documentation reveals the existence of `rowid`, or even that one can explicitly request the `rowid` does not change that it is still essentially a special metadata column, so there is really no reason for it to be included in `SELECT *` queries.

If you rely on such an integer primary key and/or insist that it appears in the full list of columns returned by `SELECT *`, then you can **add an alias for the `rowid` by defining an explicit integer primary key**.  See [sqlite CREATE TABLE docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) for details.  Here is just one example from the documentation that creates a valid rowid alias:

> > CREATE TABLE t(x INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, y, z);