# Why I can't delete a data from my application (Python and SQLite)

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sql-delete

I am trying to create one function that deletes product by its rowid from SQLite
For example I have 4 product ;

1 - Example 1

2 - Example 2

3 - Example 3

4 - Example 4

and I decide to delete Example 1,3,4 . Example 2 remains like :

1 - Example 2

The problem is I can't delete it. I don't get any error just I can't delete it.
These are my codes to connect database , list and show products and delete selected one

My code for database connection:

```
class Database:

def __init__(self):
    self.latest_row_id = 0
    self.connect_database()

def connect_database(self):
    # Connected to the database
    self.connect = sqlite3.connect("bike_rental.db")
    self.cursor = self.connect.cursor()

    self.cursor.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(name TEXT,speed TEXT,typ TEXT,stock INT,price INT)")

    self.connect.commit()
```

My code for showing products:

```
    def show_products(self):
    message = "Welcome, you can control products from this page".upper()
    print(message)
    print("-" * len(message))

    while True:

        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM products")

        all_products = self.cursor.fetchall()

        convert_all_str = lambda x: [str(y) for y in x]

        print("ID  Name             Speed         Type          Stock       Cost")

        for i,j in enumerate(all_products,1):
            print("-" * 75)
            print("{} - {} TRY".format(i,"          ".join(convert_all_str(j))))
            self.latest_row_id = i
            print("-" * 75)

        break
    return all_products
```

My code for deleting products:

```
    def delete_products(self):
    while True:
        try:
            selected_row_id = int(input("Enter id of product you want to delete: "))
            if selected_row_id <= 0 or selected_row_id > self.latest_row_id:
                print(f"\033[31mYou entered invalid value. You should enter id more than zero(0) and less than {self.latest_row_id}\033[m")
                continue

            print("\033[1;32mYou have successfully deleted the selected product.\033[m")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("\033[31mYou entered invalid value. Please enter integer number\033[m")

    self.cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM products WHERE rowid = {selected_row_id}")
    self.connect.commit()
```

Comment: preferred `execute("DELETE FROM products WHERE rowid = ?" (selected_row_id, ))`

Comment: you create table `products(name TEXT,speed TEXT,typ TEXT,stock INT,price INT)` and there is NO `rowid`. maybe you should add own column `id` instead of use `rowid`.

Comment: @furas It's an internal column, you don't have to declare it explicitly. But using an explicit column is generally preferred.

Comment: you use `enumerate()` to display row number but it has nothing to do with real `rowid` - and real `rowid` can be totally different.

Comment: @furas do you suggest me to use id instead of rowid ?

Comment: @Barmar do you suggest me to use id instead of rowid ?

Comment: Add an auto-increment ID column to the table.

Comment: @furas what should I use instead of enumerate() to display row number ?

Comment: I suggest to add own column `ID` with `auto-increment` and display this value to see what value to use when you delete.

Comment: @Barmar I've heard that auto-increment not suggested before. I guess it uses so much RAM(?)

Comment: this post [sqlite get ROWID - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570096/sqlite-get-rowid) suggets to use `SELECT rowid, * ... ` to get `rowid`

Comment: Nope, it's the standard way to do this in databases.

Comment: Thank you both for helping :)

Comment: @Barmar well I started to use auto-increment but there is one problem id doesn't decrease automatically when I delete one product. Like there is 3 different products and I delete 2nd one, 3rd's ID doesn't go to 2 from 3

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Nothing requires that IDs be consecutive. You don't want to change all the IDs because there will be foreign keys referencing them from other tables.

Comment: Oh you are right. Actually I wanted to use IDs in different use, like 1- Apple, 2- Banana, 3 - Watermelon ... I wanted to define IDs as these numbers so whenever user wants to choose or delete or update Apple, they can just enter "1" not "Apple"